# how to get stdout when executing tests with vstest.console.exe?

Tags: visual-c++, vstest, vstest.console.exe

I have some code that outputs to stdout:

```
std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
```

I have a test written with Microsoft Unit Test Framework that calls that code.  I then call the test:

```
vstest.console.exe myCode.dll
```

I expect to see "foo" but I don't see any stdout from my code.  How do I see stuff that my code has written to stdout?

To be clear, I'm not talking about using `Logger::WriteMessage()`, or any other method of printing a message from the test code.  I am talking about seeing stdout from the code under test.

Honestly I feel insane for asking something so basic, something that other test frameworks don't make difficult, but my colleagues are also at a loss.  What's the missing magic?